# SQL server IN Clause usage with Pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a problem with pivoting a table on MSSQL.
The main problem is, when I want to fetch row values in an inner query (with IN clause) I get syntax errors but when I type the values statically, it works.

So the question is, how can I use `IN` clause inside `PIVOT` clause?

The error I get is `Incorrect syntax near SELECT expecting ID,Quoted_ID or '.'` when I try inner select query.

Full sql query is listed below.
`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [SCHEMA].[get_timeseries_by_campaign_id_and_period] (
    @campaign_id INT,
    @start_date DATE NULL,
    @end_date DATE NULL)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
WITH timeseries_data AS
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN t.data_type = 'int' THEN ti.datetime
              WHEN t.data_type = 'real' THEN tr.datetime
              WHEN t.data_type = 'text' THEN tt.datetime
              ELSE 'No Data'
          END AS timeseries_date,
          c.campaign_id,
          t.timeseries_id,
          t.data_type,
          CASE
              WHEN t.data_type = 'int' THEN ti.value
              WHEN t.data_type = 'real' THEN tr.value
              WHEN t.data_type = 'text' THEN tt.value
              ELSE 'No Data'
          END AS timeseries_value
   FROM [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[hub_campaign] c
   INNER JOIN [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[measurement] m ON c.campaign_id = @campaign_id AND m.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
   INNER JOIN [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[timeseries] t ON t.measurement_id = m.measurement_id
   INNER JOIN [SCHEMA].[timeseries_view] tv ON tv.campaign_bk = c.campaign_bk
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[timeseries_data_int] AS ti ON t.timeseries_id = ti.timeseries_id 
        AND COALESCE(@start_date, GETDATE() - 1) <= ti.datetime AND ti.datetime < COALESCE(@end_date, GETDATE())
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[timeseries_data_real] AS tr ON t.timeseries_id = tr.timeseries_id
        AND COALESCE(@start_date, GETDATE() - 1) <= tr.datetime AND tr.datetime < COALESCE(@end_date, GETDATE())
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[timeseries_data_text] AS tt ON t.timeseries_id = tt.timeseries_id
        AND COALESCE(@start_date, GETDATE() - 1) <= tt.datetime AND tt.datetime < COALESCE(@end_date, GETDATE())
   ),
timeseries_ids AS (
    SELECT CONCAT('[', timeseries_id, ']') as timeseries_id FROM timeseries_data
)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT timeseries_date, timeseries_id,  timeseries_value, data_type
    FROM timeseries_data
) tmp PIVOT (
    -- AVG(timeseries_value) FOR tmp.timeseries_id IN (SELECT timeseries_id FROM timeseries_ids)
    AVG(timeseries_value) FOR tmp.timeseries_id IN ([1], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [16], [14], [15], [17], [22], [26], [23], [25], [27])
)as pvt;


SELECT * FROM [SCHEMA].[get_timeseries_by_campaign_id_and_period](1, '2021-05-29 18:00:00.00', '2021-05-30 08:00:00.00');
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I wanted to be as clear as possible.

Comment: The `IN` inside the `PIVOT` clause is not your regular `IN` predicate. Each item included there *must* be specified explicitly. What you are looking to do appears to be *dynamic pivoting*, and, coupled with the `sql-server` tag, that's the term that you want to search this or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/) site for in order to get a general picture of how it's typically done in T-SQL.

Comment: I thought here would be better for this question. Thanks for your advice.